# Resolution specific dimensions are not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen, android-layoutparams, android-resolution

I had to adjust the layout dimensions for HDPI devices. So, I added the dimensions in `values-hdpi` folder.

dimen decleration in `values-hdpi` folder

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="tracking_activity_marging_top">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimenn decleration in `values` folder

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="tracking_activity_marging_top">14dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The dimen value defined in values-hdpi folder is correctly picked in HDPI device. But, XXHDPI device (and device with non-hdpi resolution) picked the value from `values-hdpi` folder instead of normal `values` folder.

Why non-hdpi devices are picking values from hdpi folder? How can I solve it?

- The issue is happening in a library module. The dimens are picking correctly in app module.

Answer (score 0):

Each modules have its own resource folder, you might want to add dimens qualifier depending on screen dpi for library module too.

Comment: That's what I did.  The library module dependency is added in app module. So, we won't be able access the dimen value in app module from a library module.